# django translation can't decode

Tags: python, django

in django.po i have this .

```
msgid "%(message)s come from weixiang http:///www.iweix.cn "
msgstr "%(message)s 来自微X http:///www.iweix.cn"
```

and in view i have , (i have add # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-) .

```
sina_weibo_post(self.user,_("%(message)s come from weixiang http:///www.iweix.cn ")%{"message":self.photo.desc},photo_adr)
```

i got the error:

```
sina_weibo_post(self.user,_("%(message)s come from weixiang http:///www.iweix.cn")%{"message":self.photo.desc},photo_adr)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

how can i solve it ?thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check that you have a header like this, in the po file:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: 1.0.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-10-04 13:06-0500\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: XXXXX\n"
"Language-Team: Es XXXX\n"
"Language: Es\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

This line is very important:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

Comment: Perfect, it helped me.
The strange thing is that the first time I ran the command to generate the translations, he set up the header, but the second time he didn't. Anyway I copied the header from another app and everything is working 100% now.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible fix is using [`ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code) instead of `gettext` or `gettext_lazy` if your’re using Python 2 and Django <=1.11 as was suggested here: [Django Translation UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238569/django-translation-unicodedecodeerror#comment87494951_50238569)