# Django Translation UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django

I'm getting this error

> return _("%(user)s liked this") % {'user':
> likes.first().user.get_full_name()}
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
> can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

My django.po file is

```
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2018-05-08 16:21+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"


#: posts/models.py:1528 posts/models.py:1533
#, python-format
msgid "%(user)s liked this"
msgstr "%(user)s kişi sevdi"
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using python 2?

Comment: did you try to explicitly telling that it is unicode like `u"%(user)s kişi sevdi"`

Comment: @Lemayzeur That string is in a `.po` file. You should be able to use unicode there with no problem. `u"..."` only makes sense in python 2 code.

Comment: Yes I'm using python 2.7

Comment: let me try with u''

Comment: makemessages is not working project/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:681: keyword "u" unknown
msgmerge: found 3 fatal errors

Comment: @HakenLid it's just an example with a string that contains non-ASCII letter

Comment: What is `_` here? There are several gettext functions available. Are you using `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`?

Comment: from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

Comment: Use `ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy` for unicode (this has changed in django 2.0, because the current version no longer supports python 2, and everything is unicode by default). If you are stuck with an older version of python/django, you can still consult old docs. For example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code

Comment: Its worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @HåkenLid Can you write that as an answer? It also helped me tackling the problem in Python 2. The question might need some elaboration as well though.